# Dynamic header and footer in Laravel markdown mail

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-mail

Following the documentation, I have created my own mail template using markdown mailables: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#generating-markdown-mailables

The point is that I need to customize information in both the header and footer dynamically (in each situation it will be different). The information I pass in the toMail function is only available in the scope of my custom template neworder.blade.php:

```
public function toMail($notifiable){
    $from = 'no-reply.'.$this->subdomain.'@'.env('APP_DOMAIN');
    return (new MailMessage)
    ->from($from)
    ->markdown('emails.neworder',
        [
            'name'=>$this->name,
            'order'=> $this->order,
            'emailbody'=> $this->emailbody,
            'headertitle' => $this->headertitle,
            'footertext' => $this->footertext
        ]
    );
}
```

Following the same documentation, I have exported the Markdown mail components to customize them with this command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

From here I can customize files like /vendor/mail/html/themes/header.blade.php, where the modifications effectively affect the header. What I can't figure out is **how to pass variables that I can use in the scope of these files just like in /views/email/neworder.blade.php**
I need to have the values of `headertitle` and `footertext` in the corresponding sections.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I didn't get it properly. I used session variables

Comment: Do you mind updating it with how you got it done? I am having a similar issue

Comment: there you have it. All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with a `MailMessage`. You need to create a `Mailable` class and pass it in the `toMail()` function of your `Notification`.

1. Create a new `Mailable` class.
2. Make it so that your `Mailable` class uses your markdown `Blade` template file.
3. Pass the data as usual in the `markdown()` function.

```
// app/Mail/NewOrderMail.php

public function build()
{
    return $this->markdown('emails.new-order', [
        'headerTitle' => 'Header title here',
        'footerText' => 'Footer text here',
    ]);
}
```

4. In your `Mailable`'s markdown `Blade` template file, can pass the data to the layout file like so:

```
// resources/views/emails/new-order.blade.php

@component('mail::message', ['headerTitle' => $headerTitle, 'footerText' => $footerText])   
{{-- ...the rest of your email template... --}}
@endcomponent
```

5. In `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/message.blade.php`, pass the variables to each of the `@component` that you want to pass the data to:

```
// resources/views/vendor/mail/html/message.blade.php

@component('mail::layout')

{{-- Header --}}
@slot('header')
@component('mail::header', ['url' => config('app.url'), 'headerTitle' => $headerTitle ?? config('app.name')])
{{ $headerTitle }}
@endcomponent
@endslot

{{-- ...the rest of your layout template... --}}

{{-- Footer --}}
@slot('footer')
@component('mail::footer', ['footerText' => $footerText ?? 'Default Text'])
{{ $footerText }}
@endcomponent
@endslot

@endcomponent
```

6. Return your `Mailable` class in the `toMail()` function of your `Notification` class:

```
// app/Notifications/NewOrderNotification.php

public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new NewOrderMail($notifiable))->to($notifiable);
}
```

**IMPORTANT:** Make sure to *null coalesce* your variables in your `resources/views/vendor/mail/html/message.blade.php` layout file to make sure things don't break when an email template file does not pass any of the variables you defined in the layout file.

*All filenames are only used as examples. Replace them with your own.*

Answer (score 2):

Not finding a better solution, I was eventually forced to use session variables so I could use them in the header and footer templates.

1. Set session variables witch you want to use in footer/header in Http/Notifications/yourNotificationTemplate.php:

   ```
    public function toMail($notifiable){
        session(['headertitle' => $this->headertitle]);
        session(['footertext' => $this->footertext]);
        $from = 'no-reply.'.$this->subdomain.'@'.env('APP_DOMAIN');
        return (new MailMessage)
        ->from($from)
        ->markdown('emails.neworder',
            [
                'name'=>$this->name,
                'order'=> $this->order,
                'emailbody'=> $this->emailbody,
            ]
        );
    }
   ```
2. Then you are able to use it anywhere in yours templates. F.E in /views/vendor/mail/thml/header.blade.php:

```
@php ($headertext = session('headertitle'))
<tr>
<td class="header">
@if (null!==(session('headertext')))
<h1>{{$headertext}}</h1>
@else
{{ $slot }}
@endif
</td>
</tr>
```